# Remove all script elements using puppeteerSharp

Tags: c#, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I need to remove all script nodes from a page before saving the body of the page. How can I remove all script nodes from a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```cs
await page.EvaluateExpressionAsync("document.querySelectorAll('SCRIPT').forEach(e => e.remove())");
```